# Function to store fetch api call as local variable (not promise)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, promise, fetch-api

I am sending api requests to a database in order to receive data inside a widget, perform a little bit of processing on the data, then plot it and render it to my web page. This is being done in a react web app.

I am using fetch to get the data and receiving a promise. The fetching is being done inside a function which I will later call multiple times. I have found examples of how to directly console.log the data from fetch promises when making api calls, but doing this inside a function always seems to result in a promise for me... I have no idea how to return the data!

Any help that can be provided would be very much appreciated. My current code is below and returns a promise.

Thank you.

```
class MyWidget extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

async fetchData(url) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

async readDB(url) {
    const data = await this.fetchData(url);
    return data
}

processingFunction() {
    const url = 'my/database/api/variable=X'
    const database_data = this.readDB(url)
    // perform processing on database data...
    // plot processed data...
}
```

Comment: You're already doing this in the `readDB` and `fetchData` functions. What's different about `processingFunction`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `await` in the `processingFunction` which also has to be changed to `async`

```
async processingFunction() {                      // change to async
    const url = 'my/database/api/variable=X'
    const database_data = await this.readDB(url); // await the async result
    // perform processing on database data...
    // plot processed data...
}
```

but it seems that you don't need the `readDB` func at all

```
async processingFunction() {
    const url = 'my/database/api/variable=X'
    const database_data = await this.fetchData(url);

}
```

**UPDATE**

You cannot convert Promise into Array or else. There is a certain flow in React: state + life-cycle hooks. In this case you have to store data in state and use `componentDidMount` hook

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class MyWidget extends Component {
  state = {
    dataFromDB: null // set initial state
  };

  processingFunction() {
    const yourData = this.state.dataFromDB;
    // perform processing on database data...
    // plot processed data...
  }
  
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "my/database/api/variable=X";
    const database_data = await this.fetchData(url);
    
    this.setState(() => ({
      dataFromDB: database_data // set data in state from DB
    }));
  }
  
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have done that, then returned the value of database_data ("return database_data") and it is still a promise. similarly the value of database_data inside processingFunction is a promise, so I cannot access the data to process it. Does that make sense? I need to convert it to an array or something usable first. Do you know how I can return the data rather than the promise? The data itself is in json format, I know the url request works as I can test it directly in the browser.

Comment: just set the data to `state` and then work with the `state`

Comment: @Hamo I have updated the answer so you can try this solution

Comment: Thanks very much. I've just tried that (took me a while to notice the processing function is no longer asynchronous). Oddly, my state value for dataFromDB is not updating and stays null. Does it work at your end? Thank you

Comment: but where and when do you call `processingFunction` ?

Comment: I have another function inside MyWidget which is called renderPlot. This function will plot the processed data and has a call to processingFunction like this: "processed_data = processingFunction()", because the processingFunction now has a retrun statement "return processed_data".

Comment: well it depends, I haven't seen all the code. Why don't you just call `renderPlot` right after the data is fetched and unpacked in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: just right after  this line ` const database_data = await this.fetchData(url);`

Comment: Yes I have done that now, the processing function wasn't really helping anything. And it now works with your solution, I just had an issue where I wasn't correctly updating the url so fetch wasn't working.. Thank you very much for your help!